# How to catch-all URLs with MapHttpRoute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

In addition to all the defined api routes, I want to handle any other url in a LegacyUriRedirect action.

I have tried to leave the routeTemplate empty, but it catches only the root url and ignores any urls with segments.

How do I change the below code so that it catches all urls with any segments?

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "LegacyUriRedirect",
                routeTemplate: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "URI", action = "LegacyUriRedirect" }
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "LegacyUriRedirect",
        routeTemplate: "{*catchall}",
        defaults: new { controller = "URI", action = "LegacyUriRedirect" }
    );
```

Comment: I have found that just adding this to my code doesn't work in 2017 for whatever reason. Would you mind elaborating on it? words like 'legacy' suggest that this shouldn't be used...